# Android Switch Button Drag off Click/Drag On

Tags: android, uibutton, uiswitch

I had some specific questions regarding the Android switch button and creating some customized behavior. So... What I need is to only allow the switch to be draggable when transitioning from the OFF position to the ON position. I was able to get it so that if I click the switch when in the off position, it will not transition. BUT, I don't want to be able to fling the switch from the off position to the on position. I want the user to have to constantly drag it. Now you may think that a seek bar is what I'm looking for. Maybe, but I need the text transition on the thumb portion to go from Off to On when making the switch. This doesn't look like its really an option when using a Seek Bar. Also, if the user clicks the thumb when in the on position, it can make the transition to the off position. Also, there is no in between. If the user goes from off to on (dragging only), they must go all the way to the end. Any help is appreciated. My basic code is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView switchStatus;


private Switch mySwitch;

 private Handler handler = new Handler();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  switchStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.switchStatus);
  mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

  //set the switch to ON 
  mySwitch.setChecked(true);
  //attach a listener to check for changes in state
  mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
     boolean isChecked) {

    if(isChecked){
     switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");
    }else{
     switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
    }

   }
  });

  mySwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mySwitch.isChecked()) {
            mySwitch.setChecked(false);
        }
    }   
  }); 

  //check the current state before we display the screen
  if(mySwitch.isChecked()){
   switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");
  }
  else {
   switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
  }
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  return true;
 }

}
```

Comment: I'd use a seek bar, but I need it to look exactly like the switch button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured out a solution that isn't the most elegant, but i works. I extended off of the switch control and created an interface for objects that want to act upon certain drag events. Please see below.

```
public class CustomSwitch extends Switch {

   private static final String TAG = CustomSwitch.class.getSimpleName();

   private Method getThumbScrollRange;

   private int thumbScrollRange;
   private float thumbPosition;

   private boolean isMiddleOn = false;
   private boolean isMiddleOff = true;
   private boolean isOnMax = false;
   private boolean isOffMin = true;
   private boolean isMoving = false;

   private final int PIVOT_PERCENT = 50;
   private final int OFF_PERCENT_TOLERANCE = 10;
   private final int ON_PERCENT_TOLERANCE = 10;
   private final int ON_MAX_PERCENT = 100;
   private final int OFF_MIN_PERCENT = 0;

   private onDraggableSwitchListener onDraggableSwitchListener;

   public CustomSwitch(Context context) {
      this(context, null);
   }

   public CustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context, attrs, 0);
   }

   public CustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs);

      this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
         // set via variable since the switch will trigger a move
         // action on toggle, but the on draw event will trigger
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
               isMoving = true;
            }
            else {
               isMoving = false;
            }
            if (onDraggableSwitchListener != null) {
               onDraggableSwitchListener.onTouchEvent(v, event);
            }
            return false;
         }
      });

      this.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            isOnMax = isMiddleOn = isChecked;
            isOffMin = isMiddleOff = !isChecked;

            if (onDraggableSwitchListener != null) {
               onDraggableSwitchListener.onCheckedChanged(buttonView, isChecked);
            }
         }
      });

      try {
         getThumbScrollRange = Switch.class.getDeclaredMethod("getThumbScrollRange");
         getThumbScrollRange.setAccessible(true);
      }
      catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
      }
   }

   /**
    * Registers the {@link on}
    * */
   public void setOnDraggableSwitchListener(onDraggableSwitchListener listener) {
      onDraggableSwitchListener = listener;
   }

   @Override
   public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
      try {
         thumbScrollRange = (Integer) getThumbScrollRange.invoke(this);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "", e);
      }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      super.onDraw(canvas);
      try {
         thumbPosition = getField("mThumbPosition").getFloat(this);
         int percentage = (thumbScrollRange == 0 ? 0 : ((int) ((thumbPosition / thumbScrollRange) * 100)));

         Log.v(TAG, "Percentage: " + percentage);

         if ((percentage > PIVOT_PERCENT) && !isMiddleOn && isMoving) {
            if (onDraggableSwitchListener != null) onDraggableSwitchListener.onDraggableSwitchOnMiddle(percentage);
            isMiddleOn = true;
            isOffMin = isMiddleOff = false;
            Log.v(TAG, "MIDDLE ON TRUE");
         }
         else if ((percentage < PIVOT_PERCENT) && !isMiddleOff && isMoving) {
            if (onDraggableSwitchListener != null) onDraggableSwitchListener.onDraggableSwitchOffMiddle(percentage);
            isMiddleOff = true;
            isOnMax = isMiddleOn = false;
            Log.v(TAG, "MIDDLE OFF TRUE");
         }

         if ((percentage <= (OFF_MIN_PERCENT + OFF_PERCENT_TOLERANCE)) && !isOffMin && isMoving) {
            if (onDraggableSwitchListener != null) onDraggableSwitchListener.onDraggableSwitchOffMin();
            isOffMin = true;
            Log.v(TAG, "OFF MIN TRUE");
         }
         else if ((percentage >= (ON_MAX_PERCENT - ON_PERCENT_TOLERANCE)) && !isOnMax && isMoving) {
            if (onDraggableSwitchListener != null) onDraggableSwitchListener.onDraggableSwitchOnMax();
            isOnMax = true;
            Log.v(TAG, "ON MAX TRUE");
         }
      }
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "", e);
      }
      catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "", e);
      }
   }

   /** Cache of private fields from superclass */
   private Map<String, Field> fieldCache = new HashMap<String, Field>();

   private Field getField(String name) {

      try {
         if (!fieldCache.containsKey(name)) {
            Field f = Switch.class.getDeclaredField(name);
            f.setAccessible(true);
            fieldCache.put(name, f);
         }
         return fieldCache.get(name);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
   }

   public static interface onDraggableSwitchListener {

      public void onDraggableSwitchOnMax();

      public void onDraggableSwitchOffMin();

      public void onDraggableSwitchOnMiddle(int percentage);

      public void onDraggableSwitchOffMiddle(int percentage);

      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked);

      public void onTouchEvent(View v, MotionEvent event);
   }
}
```

All you have to do now is use this switch in your layout and then in your main class you can setup the appropriate listeners. Hope this helps someone (even though it is pretty specific).

Comment: I am using your custom class, unfortunately in my case Switch responses to the clicks and changes it's checked state.